# Regex that covers multiple date formats

Tags: java, regex

What regex to choose to cover all the following scenarios:
Basically I have to extract prefix and suffix.

**prefix.YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS.suffix**

YYYY-MM-DD is mandatory.

HH-MM-SS is optional. (It could be HH only or HH-MM or HH-MM-SS)

Samples:

"test1.2020-03-07-00.test.com",

"test2.2020-03-06-16.test2.test1.com",

"test3.2020-03-06-16-13-40.test2.test1.com",

"test4.2020-03-06-16-13.test.com",

"test5.ext.2020-03-11-17-57.test1.com"

"test6.ext.2020-03-11.test1.test2.test3.com"

I use this regex but it fails:

```
Pattern.compile(".\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}(-\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})?.*?");
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all, or are you just looking for us to write your code for you, because you can't be bothered to learn regex? If you did try something, show what you've tried, and explain where/why you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
(.+)\.\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2,5}\.(.+)
```

```
(.+)                      capturing group for the prefix.
\.                        literal dot.
\d{4}                     4 digits.
(?:-\d{2}){2,5}           non-capturing group for literal dash followed by 2 digits,
                          repeated at least 2 times and at most 5 times.
\.                        literal dot.
(.+)                      capturing group for the suffix.
```

---

For example:

```
var pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+)\\.\\d{4}(?:-\\d{2}){2,5}\\.(.+)");
var matcher = pattern.matcher("test1.2020-03-07-00.test.com");
if(matcher.matches())
{
    String prefix = matcher.group(1);
    String suffix = matcher.group(2);

    System.out.println("prefix: " + prefix);
    System.out.println("suffix: " + suffix);
}
```

Output:

```
prefix: test1
suffix: test.com
```

Comment: `groupCount()` depends on the pattern, not the input, so since the pattern is a hardcoded literal, `groupCount() == 2` cannot be false, and is entirely redundant.

Answer (score 1):

First remember that `.` period is a special regex pattern matching any character, so to specifically match a period, you need to escape it as `\.`

You said yourself that the time part *"could be HH only or HH-MM or HH-MM-SS"*, so you shouldn't expect `(-\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})?` to match that. Since you don't need to capture it, use a `(?:...)` non-capturing group, and nest them: `(?:-\\d{2}(?:-\\d{2}(?:-\\d{2})?)?)?`. Better yet, since the 3 parts are the same, use `(?:-\\d{2}){0,3}`

You said *"I have to extract prefix and suffix"*, so you should add that to the pattern.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)\\.(\\d{4}(?:-\\d{2}){2,5})\\.(.*)$");
for (String s : new String[] { "test1.2020-03-07-00.test.com",
                               "test2.2020-03-06-16.test2.test1.com",
                               "test3.2020-03-06-16-13-40.test2.test1.com",
                               "test4.2020-03-06-16-13.test.com",
                               "test5.ext.2020-03-11-17-57.test1.com",
                               "test6.ext.2020-03-11.test1.test2.test3.com" }) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.printf("prefix = '%s', date = '%s', suffix = '%s'%n",
                          m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3));
    } else {
        System.out.printf("NO MATCH: '%s'%n", s);
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
prefix = 'test1', date = '2020-03-07-00', suffix = 'test.com'
prefix = 'test2', date = '2020-03-06-16', suffix = 'test2.test1.com'
prefix = 'test3', date = '2020-03-06-16-13-40', suffix = 'test2.test1.com'
prefix = 'test4', date = '2020-03-06-16-13', suffix = 'test.com'
prefix = 'test5.ext', date = '2020-03-11-17-57', suffix = 'test1.com'
prefix = 'test6.ext', date = '2020-03-11', suffix = 'test1.test2.test3.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different approach. Finding an appropriate Regex would be very difficult if not impossible. I dealt with an issue of parsing a date from any possible format that is not known in advance and I came up with an idea. Of course, there is no 100% solution to this issue but here what I did. I created a property file that contains a list of currently supported formats. When a String needs to be parsed the attempts are made consecutively with each mask until you successfully parse the date or until you run out of masks. The pros of the idea
 1. since the file is an external file it could be constantly updated with additional formats without any need to change the code.
 2. file could be customized on the per-customer base where you place more preferable formats first. For example, for US-based customers, you would place US formats first (such as MM-dd-YYYY and after that European formats. And vise-versa for European-based customers. So when the date such as 07-08-2000 comes in, for US-based customers it would be parsed as July 8th but for European customers, it would be parsed as August 7th. So, in short - flexibility.
For more details read my article on the topic - [Java 8 java.time package: parsing any string to date](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/java-8-javatime-package-parsing-any-string-date-michael-gantman/)